# Possible to customize Terminal context (right-click) menu?

Tags: command-line, customization, gnome-terminal, context-menu

I am making the transition to `Ubuntu 10.0.04` from years of Windows. It would help if the terminal could have the right-click context menu display the `copy` command first in the command list, instead of like, 4th. There must be a way to change the ordering of items in the context menu. How would you configure the Terminal (or any) context menu in Ubuntu?

Comment: For completeness, please specify the version and flavor of Ubuntu involved. Each flavor has its own version of terminal.

Comment: Just a comment about the last part of the question: the only context menus I could configure were those of the Firefox and Opera browsers. And that is OS-independent.

Comment: Do you know that you can *just select* text to have it on the clipboard already? It's a different clipboard, but you can still paste with middle-button or Shift+Insert.

Comment: @vasa1 Ubuntu 10.0.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: I don't know if it is per-user configurable.

But a workaround is possible thanks to the easy to edit XML files, which describe the user interface. On Ubuntu 12.10, in the file `/usr/share/gnome-terminal/terminal.xml` simply move the line `<menuitem action="PopupCopy" />` to the top below `<popup name="Popup" action="Popup">`. Or to be semantically consistent:

```
diff --git a/terminal.xml b/terminal.xml
index 3c9cbed..f7b7757 100644
--- a/terminal.xml
+++ b/terminal.xml
@@ -78,6 +78,10 @@
   </menubar>

   <popup name="Popup" action="Popup">
+    <menuitem action="PopupCopy" />
+    <menuitem action="PopupPaste" />
+    <menuitem action="PopupPasteURIPaths" />
+    <separator />
     <menuitem action="PopupSendEmail" />
     <menuitem action="PopupCopyEmailAddress" />
     <menuitem action="PopupCall" />
@@ -91,10 +95,6 @@
     <menuitem action="PopupCloseTab" />
     <menuitem action="PopupCloseWindow" />
     <separator />
-    <menuitem action="PopupCopy" />
-    <menuitem action="PopupPaste" />
-    <menuitem action="PopupPasteURIPaths" />
-    <separator />
     <menu action="PopupTerminalProfiles">
         <placeholder name="ProfilesPH" />
         <separator />
```

Comment: Re. it being or not being per-user configurable, I don't use gnome-terminal myself and so can't check it out, but what if you save a copy as `~/.local/share/gnome-terminal/terminal.xml` and then edit *that copy* as you suggested?

Comment: Ah this would be nice. Unfortunately trying this didn't work with 12.10 as of today. I made a quick search for documentation for the cause and behaviour of ~/.local/share/ but found nothing.