# How can I edit the contextual (right-click) menu in Nautilus and Unity?

Tags: nautilus

How can I edit the contextual menu in Ubuntu?  How can I add/remove items?  Will the method for Ubuntu also work for variants such as Kubuntu/Xubuntu/Lubuntu?  Is there a configuration file that I can edit, or do I have to use a program/utility instead?

Edit: Someone pointed out that every program handles its own contextual menu.  In particular, I would like to be able to edit the contextual menus for Nautilus and the Unity desktop interface.

Comment: Won't each program have it's own contextual menu which may or may not be configurable by the end user? For example, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/251813/25656) for gnome-terminal. I also know that the context menus of Firefox and Opera are editable, but it would be very interesting to know of a way to do so generally.